# VBA - Generating multiple QueryTables?

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the code I currently have:

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim qt As QueryTable
Dim URL As String
Dim Symbol As String
Set mep = Worksheets ("Managed Equity Portfolios")
Set ws = Worksheets("Hidden Sheet 3")

Symbol = Symbol & mep.Range("B5").Value
URL = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=MUTF:" + Symbol

Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
    Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))

qt.Refresh
 Dim URL1 As String
 Dim qt1 As QueryTable
 Dim Symbol1 As String

Symbol1 = Symbol1 & mep.Range("B6").Value
URL1 = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=MUTF:" + Symbol1

 Set qt1 = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL1;" & URL1, _
    Destination:=ws.Range("J1"))
 qt1.Refresh

End Sub
```

So currently in the link, the symbol for the stock information I am trying to pull is at the end of the URL, "JLVIX"

I have all of my symbols on a different worksheet, all in Column B.

I know about yahoo API, and am using it, but it won't work because I need the 5 year standard deviation , which yahoo doesn't provide.

I would like the Macro to be able to pull the symbol from column B, and generate a QueryTable with that symbol at the end of the URL. Is there a more efficient way of doing this than creating 10 different macros with 10 different QueryTables on different worksheets?

Thank you!

Edit: It seems like when I try to make multiple QueryTables on one worksheet, they just stack on top of each other :(

Comment: do not use _With_ for one line  ... use `qt.Refresh`

Comment: Ok I will change that. Also, I tried making multiple querytables and that doesn't work either, at least not on the same worksheet as it just deletes the prior one

Comment: you can do multiples. _qt_ is a pointer to a specific table. you just need multiple pointers.  repeat `set qt   ` and `qt.Refresh` with qt1 and use a different range _range("D1")_ for example.

Comment: Hey, so I tried that but it ended up stacking them on top of each other. I'll update the code right now to show you what I mean

Comment: It's also saying "Method 'Add' of 'QueryTables' failed" Also I forgot to state I am using Excel 2011 for Mac, if that changes anything

Comment: i posted some more code. one that uses two table objects, and it works on windows machine. second code uses only one table for multiple data retrievals. you just have to process the data after each inquiry.

Comment: That second one that uses one table worked great! I had some issues with the first one because it wouldn't let me change the URL, but maybe I can incorporate them together and see how it works. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Add params to the `Sub` so you can call it for different contexts inside a loop with all the worksheets / equity symbols.

If all you need is the 5 year standard deviation you can change the `Sub` into a `Function` that returns the value.

#### EXAMPLE

```
Function get5YearStd(symbol As String) As Double

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim URL As String
    Set ws = Worksheets("Hidden Sheet 3") 'Or any other sheet

    URL = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=MUTF:" + symbol
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
        Destination:=ws.Range("A1") _
        )
    With qt
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells 'So the queries are always overwritten
        .BackgroundQuery = False 'It needs to wait before fetching the updated value
        .Refresh
    End With

    get5YearStd = ws.Range("D46").Value 'Range where the 5yr std.dev is

End Function
```

Then have another sub that call this function inside a loop for all your symbols

#### EXAMPLE

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim equities As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim stddev As Double

    Set ws = Worksheets("Managed Equity Portfolios")
    Set rng1 = ws.Range("B5:B9")
    Set rng2 = ws.Range("B11:B12")

    'Loop over each cell in the informed ranges and call the function to retrive the data
    For Each rng In Union(rng1, rng2)
        stddev = get5YearStd(rng.Value)
    Next
    Debug.Print stddev

    'Clear up connections created
    For Each cn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        cn.Delete
    Next
    'Clear variables
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rng1 = Nothing
    Set rng2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I'm a bit confused on the Sub part though, the For Each loop in particular. Is it supposed to loop through the cells and pull the symbol out and put it in to the URL? Also, when I run this, it doesn't seem to be pulling the data I need, but instead only the first row

Comment: The `for each loop` loops through all the worksheets in the workbook. I made this just as an example as I don't know how your `symbols` are stored. Are they in separete worksheets? Are they all in one worksheet?

Comment: Hey, sorry I've just started learning VBA so I'm not too good at this, but thank you so much for your help! The symbols are in cells B5:B9 and B11:B12 on a separate worksheet called "Managed Equity Portfolios" where as the query tables are put into another worksheet called "Hidden Sheet 3"

Comment: @vba.Beginner, changed my answer with the information provided now the `Sub` loops over the range with the symbols. The function retrives the information from the url and then prints the 5 year std.dev into the "Immediate window".

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I checked this out and it looks like its finally pulling data with the symbols that are in the Managed Equity Portfolio, but it's still pasting the data over each other, and it doesn't seem to be printing anything into the Immediate window. The loop works great, and I will use this to try and figure more of it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

please try this. run in new workbook

```
Sub Test()

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=MUTF:JLVIX"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim tc As Integer
    tc = ws.QueryTables.Count

    If tc > 0 Then
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = tc To 1 Step -1     ' delete any tables that may be in the worksheet
            ws.QueryTables(i).Deleteworksheet
        Next i
    End If

    Dim qt1 As QueryTable
    Set qt1 = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
        Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))

    Dim qt2 As QueryTable
    Set qt2 = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
        Destination:=ws.Range("H1"))

    qt2.Refresh                ' fill second one first, just to see what happens
    qt2.ResultRange.Select     ' this is just to highlight the range

    Stop                       ' check worksheet now

    qt1.Refresh
    qt1.ResultRange.Select     ' this is just to highlight the range



End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the response. So this works when I run it with F8, step by step, it'll give me two separate tables of JLVIX. But if I try to run the whole thing, it stops at the first For loop, at the 'ws.QueryTables(i).Delete'  I commented it out and it worked again. Sorry I'm new to this, but I wasn't too sure what that line was used for? - Will it affect the macro as I add more tables?

Comment: So I tried this with a different URL, where URL1 = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=MUTF:JLVIX" and changed the parameters in qt2 to use URL1, but now it gives me the error "subscript out of range"

Comment: my bad. the ws.QueryTables(i).Delete is part of the loop that deletes any tables already on the worksheet. it fails when you start with an empty worksheet. corrected the loop

Comment: Oh hey! Thanks for the fix, and sorry for the late reply! So one question is, should I remove the "Stop" and just let it continuously run as I pull the data? Or should I leave it in there and just keep running the macro until it finishes?

Answer (score 0):

crude example of using the same table for pulling multiple data sources.  data would be processed after each update

```
Sub Test()

    Dim URL As String
    URL = "https://www.google.com/finance?q=MUTF:JLVIX"

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To ws.QueryTables.Count
        ws.QueryTables(1).Delete
    Next i

    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="URL;" & URL, _
        Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))

    qt.Refresh
    qt.ResultRange.Select     ' this is just to highlight the range

    Stop                      ' check worksheet now

    qt.ResultRange.ClearContents

    Stop                      ' check worksheet now

    qt.Connection = "URL;https://www.google.com/finance?q=MUTF:IBM"
    qt.Destination = ws.Range("G3")   ' this does not move the range

    Stop                      ' check worksheet now

    qt.Refresh
    qt.ResultRange.Select     ' this is just to highlight the range

    Stop                      ' process data here

    qt.ResultRange.ClearContents

End Sub
```